# get current div visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am fairly new to jQuery and I am trying to achieve infinte scroll so I am able to trigger a ajax call to backend as soon as I reach the end of page. I also want to know the current div visible in viewport so that I can also issue a ajax call . LEts say I have 6 div

```
<div id="test">
            Some content here
<div>
    <div id="test1">
        more content here
    </div>
    <div id="test2">
        more content here again
    </div>
```

I want to issue ajax call if my cursor reaches to 2nd div while scrolling up, same for 3rd div and 1st div also. I am too naive in this so I may be asking a silly question but pardon me.

Comment: You cannot gave same id to more than one div. please edit it

Comment: Use `class` for repeat identifiers, `id` is a unique identifier

Comment: You might want to look into pre-existing JQuery plugins to accomplish this sort of thing.

It seems to me that simply having 'x' static divs is not a smart way of achieving an infinite scroll; you would want new divs with content to automatically be instantiated while scrolling down.

Perhaps this sort of JQuery plugin does something similar to what you want?: http://jscroll.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("div").mouseover(function(){
    $id = $(this).attr("id"); //retrieve id, e.g. test, test1, test2, etc
    //if ajax call by switch case
    switch($id){
        case "test":
            //ajax code
            break;

        case "test1":
            //ajax code
            break;
    }
    //or directly ajax
    $.ajax({...});
    //or so on
});
```

Hope this help you

Comment: But what if my mouse us not on the divv?

Comment: if not on mouseover, then can try this plugin and bellow code:

plugin: https://github.com/teamdf/jquery-visible/
code:
if ($('#element').visible(true)) {
    // The element is visible, do something
} else {
    // The element is NOT visible, do something else
}